# Convert UPDATE FROM in SQL Server to SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following schema;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MatrixElements] (
    [Id]        INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [OdPairKey] INT        NOT NULL,
    [Value]     FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
    [Matrix_Id] INT        NULL
);
```

`Matrix_Id` is a foreign key to another table. What I want to do is overwrite the values in the table with the sum of the original value and some other value that matches the same `OdPairKey` but for a different `Matrix_Id`. The following query works in SQL Server;

```
UPDATE dbo.MatrixElements
SET [Value] = O.[Value] + I.[Value]
FROM dbo.MatrixElements O
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.MatrixElements WHERE Matrix_Id = 2) I
ON O.OdPairKey = I.OdPairKey
WHERE O.Matrix_Id = 1
```

But it turns out that SQLite does not support a FROM clause on an UPDATE. I can't for the life of me work out how to convert this into a compatible SQLite query. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try getting rid of `dbo` and the square brackets.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I do not have dbo or the brackets in the SQLite version. It still doesn't work. That is not the problem. The problem is stated at the bottom of my question. SQLite doesn't support a FROM clause on an UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your query to use a correlated subquery, like this:

```
UPDATE MatrixElements
SET Value = Value + (SELECT Value FROM MatrixElements a 
        WHERE a.Matrix_Id = 2 And a.OdPairKey = MatrixElements.OdPairKey LIMIT 1)
WHERE Matrix_Id = 1
```